# An internal server error has occurred while attempting to perform this command. my command

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I'm having a problem with my command.

When I run it in game it says that an internal server error has occurred while attempting to perform this command.

Also there is some very long text in the console that I will not attempt to type out because I will mess up very badly.

Also this is my first time using arguments so I may not be doing them right but it looks quite the same as a tutorial I viewed.

```
package me.mcmatt.squidcp;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.Plugin;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import com.sk89q.worldedit.bukkit.WorldEditPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {


  public void onEnable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Squid CP booted up! Version: " + Bukkit.getPluginManager().getPlugin("SquidCarePackages").getDescription().getVersion());

  }
  public void onDisable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Squid CP shut down!");
  }

  public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    if (commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("squid")) {
      if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You must be a player to run this command");
      } else {
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if (!(args[1].toString().equalsIgnoreCase("set"))) {
          player.sendMessage("Gratz");

        }
      }
    }

    return true;

  }

  public WorldEditPlugin getWorldEdit() {
    Plugin p = Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("WorldEdit");
    if (p instanceof WorldEditPlugin) return (WorldEditPlugin) p;
    else return null;

  }

}
```

Comment: That long text in the console you mention would probably be of value to someone who could help answer this. Perhaps add that in to your question.

Comment: Also, what tutorial did you view?

Comment: No stack trace, no help. Post the error log.

Comment: Im sorry but there is no way (That i know of) to copy and paste a windows cmd promt

Comment: @McMatt Take a screenshot of it

Answer (score 1):

An internal error is most likely occurring because an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is being thrown when executing the `squid` command without supplying enough arguments. Your code assumes that the `args` array has at least length 2 and that therefore the second argument, `args[1]`, exists. `args[0]` is the first `String` in the array. When typing in just "/squid" or even "/squid set" and not specifying any further arguments, the exception is thrown since the `args` array is empty or does not contain a second element. Check whether the `args` array has the correct length by adding a check such as `if (args.length == 2) {}` or even `if (args.length > 1) {}`.

I'm guessing you meant to access only the first `String` in the `args` array. Changing `args[1]` to `args[0]` would allow the command to work the way you probably intended. However, it would be good to still make sure that the array has the correct length to avoid causing that error when a player uses the command incorrectly by providing too few or no arguments at all.

Comment: @McMatt then Consider making it an accepted answer. It helped me too, I thought the array of args would contain the `/main_command` at args[0] but it appears that the main command doesn't even exist in `args`.